# Is it custom to create a static variable inside a function using `this.temp`?

Tags: javascript

I want to utilize a static variable in a function, i.e., a variable which adheres to the following requirements:

1. It retains its value over different calls to that function
2. It is known (accessible) only within the scope of that function

Here is a generic example of how I am achieving these requirements:

```
function func(state, input) {
    switch (state) {
    case 'x':
        this.temp = calc(input);
        return this.temp;
    case 'y':
        return this.temp;
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I'd like to know if it's a custom way, and if there's a better way (cleaner, simpler, better practice, etc).

Comment: What is `this` during the call to `func`? How are you calling `func`? I strongly suspect what you're doing fails your second criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't meet your second criterion. Anything with access to the object `this` refers to has access to `this.temp`. (From the code in the question, `this` may even refer to the global object, in which case `temp` is a global accessible **everywhere**.)

If you need to have `func` store truly private information, the standard way to do that is to use a closure:

```
const func = (() => {
    let temp;
    return function func(state, input) {
        switch (state) {
        case 'x':
            temp = calc(input);
            return temp;
        case 'y':
            return temp;
        }
    };
})();
```

That runs an anonymous function when the code is run that returns the `func` to assign to the `func` constant, and uses the closure created by that call to give `func` a truly private `temp` variable.